# PHP not using session path specified in php.ini File

Tags: php, session, ini

I'm having an issue where PHP is trying to use the default session directory (/var/lib/php/session) even though I have set it to something different in my php.ini file:

```
session.save_path = "/WEB/SESSIONS"
```

I have the exact ini file on another web server and no issue.  I'm using PHP 5.5 with Apache.  I have verified that PHP is trying to use /var/lib/php/session by looking at phpinfo and from the Apache error log:

> [Mon Aug 04 14:32:18 2014] [error] [client x.x.x.x] PHP Warning: 
>   Unknown: open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_e9bvjjf77tbpo40r86e5pegl80,
>   O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0, referer:
>   https://x.x.com/

This is usually pretty straight forward for me but not sure why I'm having an issue.  Would appreciate any advice!  Thank you!

Comment: Sanity check: have you double checked the php.ini file path to make certain you're editing the right one? (I find [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) the best way of checking...)

Comment: Just a double check: have you restarted your web server? also check if it is using the php.ini file you are editing `phpinfo()`

Comment: Moreover, have you created the directory using the www-user account that apache uses? If you don't have the permissions to write in the directory you would get a permission denied error. Use `chmod 0777 /var/lib/php/session/` to give permissions to all users.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.  Verified that I'm using the correct php.ini file and restarted the web server.  I did just notice that in the phpinfo output, I have two values:  Local Value and Master Value.  The Local Value has /var/lib/php/session listed and the Master Value has the one I've specified in the php.ini file.  Not sure where the local value is coming from.  Will have to do some digging.

Comment: OK - found the issue.  Apache was specifying a local value in /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf.  I commented out the values and my server is now using the Master Value.  Thanks for your help!